# How to set default by req.body.username in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to set created_by field auto-generate by default feature in mongoose. But I am facing trouble. I cannot set req.body.username on the default state, also I already try to make variables and call it still do not work. This is my code on model:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { findByUsername } = require('../services/userService');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const username = req.body.username;

created_by: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "This field is required"],
        default: username

},
    updated_by: {
        type: String,
        required: [false, "This field is required"]
    }
}, {collection: 'ticket'});

const Ticket = mongoose.model("Ticket", TicketSchema);
module.exports = {Ticket, TicketSchema};
```

i want (created_by) field receive value from user name, i already try to get user name value by controller.js and its work. so i want default of created_by field is set with user name based on user currently logged in.

this is the code which i already try in controller.js

```
    module.exports = {
GetUsername : async function (req, res, next) {
        errors = {};
        const username = req.body.username;
        return res.status(200).json({"status": "success", "data": username});


    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get req.body.user in the mongoose schema?

Comment: First of all, your question is not clear. Second, your code is not very helpful in terms of your issue. Try to explain it and put some meaningful code.

Comment: @Shihab Hello thanks for comment, i already edic my question. the point is i want to set created_by field as default, but the value is username currently logged in. thanks

Comment: Where do you store the information of a logged-in user? Is it in `req.user` or where? To auto-populate the created_by field you have access to the logged-in user.

Comment: It is not possible to get req.body in mongoose.schema but you need to write middleware in controller like one you have already tried (GetUsername).in that middleware get document in which you want to set created_by, set username and save document